# Get type of Entity in EF TPT Inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

My domain entities are using EF Table Per Type Inheritance, and here is the relationship.

[image: table per type]

As you can see Invoices sits on the parent entity `Order.cs`. This is now creating me issues when I deal with invoices.

For instance, **to create an invoice**, I need to pass the **order Id** to the Invoice controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(int orderId)
{
  if (orderId == 0) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

  // determine whether the order is a SaleOrder or a PurchaseOrder
  // then create the viewModel passing in the SaleOrder / PurchaseOrder details
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

How do I figure out what child type an order is by simply its Id?

**UPDATE**

Theo asked how I was currently retrieving SaleOrders and PurchaseOrders. I have this in my context:

```
public DbSet<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrders { get; set; }
public DbSet<SaleOrder> SaleOrders { get; set; }
```

I have built a repository around each, so I have a `PurchaseOrderRepository` and a `SaleOrderRepository` and I do my CRUD that way.

Comment: That would depend on any number of things. Do you store your SO's and PO's in the same table or different tables? How do you actually retrieve them? is there any distinction between the range of ID's assigned to the order types? Are you averse to setting up some sort of controlling mechanism that keeps track of which ID's were assigned to which order type?

Comment: @Theo, he already stated that this is TPT strategy

Comment: Yep, each has its own table, that's what TPT "means". But I've added some other info that might be useful

Comment: Ah ... re-read, and I see that now. Not sure how I missed it.

Comment: One way to do it would be to reserve ranges for the ID's of each order type - I am not a big fan but I have seen that done in SAP implementations often enough. Alternatively, set up a "control" table that indicates by ID which type it belongs to. Are either of those feasible? Also I notice that you call the method "Create" If that is to create NEW orders, how would you know which type to create, unless you passed some sort of indicator into the method?

Comment: @Theo, that `Create` sits on the `InvoiceController`. It creates an Invoice. As for creating orders, I've already mentioned that I have a Repo for each.

Comment: Yea, I get the repo for orders, I just wasn't sure if you were creating an SO/PO there - if it's an invoice thats different. How are you getting directed to this action? Surely if you know the ID, you are coming from a location where the order was being displayed, meaning that you likely knew the type at the time you made a call to this action - add the order type into the calling parameters.

Comment: If you need to know the type behind a key then something in your design is defeating the purpose of class inheritance. Ideally you should create a (generic?) repository constraining the type to Order class hierarchy and it should do its work independently to the concrete type.

Comment: The repository is generic, I just pass it `SaleOrder` or `PurchaseOrder` :) That still doesn't help me with this issue though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two classes inherit from the same class you can create another DbSet

```
public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```

and in your Action ask for the order like this

```
    public ActionResult Create(int orderId)
    {
      if (orderId == 0) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
      var order = db.Orders.Find(orderId);
      if(order is SaleOrder){
        //do your stuff for SaleOrder
      }
      if(order is PurchaseOrder){
        //do your stuff for PurchaseOrder
      }          
      return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: hmm this has given me the idea of unifying my `SaleOrderRepository` and `PurchaseOrderRepository`! Can that be done too? Or do I need those separate if I want to for example bring back all PurchaseOrders